# Loading app taking too long

Tags: ionic2

I've build an small/simple app with ionic 2.
But when I try open  it on my phone it takes more than 10 seconds to load.
I don't know if this is an ionic2  issue for or has something to do with my code.

I tried using   enableProdMode(); but I get the same result: 10 second for loading.

my main.ts

```
{
    import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
    import { AppModule } from './app.module';
    import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
    enableProdMode();

    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
}
```

My technologies:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.3.0 
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1 
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0 
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.1.4
```

Is there a way to lower the loading time for my app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you built it like that: `ionic build android --prod --release` (or whatever platform you are using)? This should produce the best results.

Comment: I tried your  suggestion and it worked. Now it is loading faster. Thanks a lot.